# WebRTC iOS SignalEncoderTimedOut

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc

I have tried to make a video translation from iOS device to Chrome browser.
On iOS I am doing the following:

```
let conf=RTCConfiguration()
conf.iceServers=[RTCIceServer(urlStrings: ["stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"])]
let cond=RTCMediaConstraints.init(mandatoryConstraints: ["OfferToReceiveAudio":"true","OfferToReceiveVideo":"true"], optionalConstraints: [:])
self.conn=fact?.peerConnection(with: conf, constraints: cond, delegate: self)
let mcons=RTCMediaConstraints.init(mandatoryConstraints: [:], optionalConstraints: [:])
let asrc=fact?.audioSource(with: mcons)
let atrk=self.fact!.audioTrack(with: asrc!, trackId: "aud")
atrk.isEnabled=true
conn?.add(atrk, streamIds: ["str"])

let vsrc=self.fact!.videoSource()
self.vcap=RTCCameraVideoCapturer.init(delegate: vsrc)
let vtrk=self.fact!.videoTrack(with: vsrc, trackId: "vid")
conn?.add(vtrk, streamIds: ["str"])
vtrk.isEnabled=true

conn?.offer(for: RTCMediaConstraints.init(mandatoryConstraints: ["OfferToReceiveAudio":"true","OfferToReceiveVideo":"true"], optionalConstraints: nil), completionHandler: {
    (sdp,err) in do {
       ...    
    }
}
func peerConnection(_ peerConnection: RTCPeerConnection, didChange newState: RTCIceConnectionState) {
    switch newState {
     ...
    case RTCIceConnectionState.connected:
        self.log(msg: "RTCIceConnectionState: connected")

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let cam=AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: AVMediaType.video, position: .back)
            let formats=RTCCameraVideoCapturer.supportedFormats(for: cam!)
            let form=formats[0]
            self.vcap!.startCapture(with: cam!, format: form, fps: 10) {
                err in
            }
        }
        break
        ...
    }
}
```

I have a successfull connection, the other side got audio and video tracks, but no video is transmitted.
The logs on iOS devive shows me the following line:

```
 (video_send_stream_impl.cc:580): SignalEncoderTimedOut, Encoder timed out.
```

How to get the video translation working?

I also see the audio capturing and transmitting, but hear no sound from chrome.

GoogleWebRTC (1.1.23260)

iOS 11.3.1 (iPhone SE)

Xcode 9.3.1 (9E501)

Chrome  66.0.3359.181 64Bit on MacOS

Comment: I have checked on Firefox -- I can hear audio, bot still no video.

Comment: I also found that there is no Ice candidates from browser with sdpMid:"video". But there is also no candidates with sdpMid:"data" and data channel works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by retaining vsrc.

Comment: Pavel, can you explain this a bit more and show exactly what you did. I am having the EXACT same problem (including hearing audio on Firefox but not on Chrome) but I cannot seem to fix it. Thx.

Comment: @cbiggin, Swift has very agressive garbage collector, ALL objects, which are not retained will be destroyed soon. WebRTC library don't retaining some auxiliary objects, like videoSource, so you must do it yourself too keep them working.